# Implicit arguments in Idris

Tags: idris

I need some help interpreting an error message regarding implicit arguments in Idris and why a small change fixes it. This is the code:

```
import Data.Vect

myReverse : Vect n elem -> Vect n elem
myReverse [] = []
myReverse {n} (x :: xs)
  = let result = myReverse xs ++ [x] in
                 ?rhs
```

It results in this error:

```
When checking left hand side of myReverse:
When checking an application of Main.myReverse:
        Type mismatch between
                Vect (S len) elem (Type of x :: xs)
        and
                Vect n elem (Expected type)

        Specifically:
                Type mismatch between
                        S len
                and
                        n
```

However, replacing `{n}` with `{n = S len}`, the code type-checks.

1. I thought that using `{n}` was simply meant to bring the implicit `n` argument of the function into scope. Why would this result in an error?
2. What does the error message mean? The only interpretation I can think of is that the implicit argument `n` in the type is rewritten due to pattern-matching `x::xs` into `S len`, and Idris loses information that these are the same.
3. How does replacing it with `{n = S len}` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet in these cases is to use idris to do the programming for you. If you start with

```
myReverse : Vect n elem -> Vect n elem
myReverse {n} xs = ?myReverse_rhs
```

and now case split on xs you get

```
myReverse : Vect n elem -> Vect n elem
myReverse {n = Z} [] = ?myReverse_rhs_1
myReverse {n = (S len)} (x :: xs) = ?myReverse_rhs_2
```

So not only did idris do a case split on xs, but also on n, since for an empty vector the length must be Z, and for a nonempty vector it must be at least S len. Which also implies that xs is now of length len.

Since n is also on the right hand side of your function, it is obvious that you need to provide something for myReverse_rhs_2 which is of length S len which equals n when you did the pattern matching right.

In the error message idris doesn't know what n is, hence the message.

Comment: The right hand side isn't causing this (you can check by giving the function the type `Vect n elem -> Vect j elem`). `{n}` is shorthand for `{n=n}`. So Idris tries to unify on the left hand side `n` with `S (len)` from `(x :: xs)` - which of course fails, `n` could match any `Nat`, even `Z`.